# Multiple bootstrap carousels with different settings

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

There are multiple carousels in my page and they all work the same way.

I'd like to make one of them have different settings though (interval), but I can't make it happen.

[Here is the fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/ktsixit/occ9akmv/)

I'd like to have "#slideshow" carousel work with interval/auto slide set to active, and the rest of them to have interval/auto slide disabled.

```
jQuery('.carousel').each(function () {
    jQuery(this).carousel({
        interval: false
    });
    jQuery('#slideshow').carousel({
        interval: 3000
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get rid of most of the jQuery you've written and leave only this:

```
$('#slideshow').carousel({
    interval: 3000
});
```

**[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/degoeym/mf9L02et/)**

My solution is simply a fork of your code with the unneeded jQuery removed.

Also, note that you can simply type $ instead of jQuery all the time.

Finally, you forgot to choose a version of jQuery in your Fiddle. :P

Comment: Your code works for the first carousel, but leaves the rest inactive. I want to have one statement for the slideshow carousel (with enabled interval) and one statement for the rest of the carousels (with interval disabled)

Comment: What do you mean by "inactive"? You said in your question that you want the first one to slide on a set interval, and the other two to not slide automatically but still be movable via the user controls. That's how I'm reading it, anyway.

Comment: I understand how #slideshow works, but how do the rest of the carousels work, withour having any statement about them?

Comment: They have default settings as part of Bootstrap. The jQuery and events you can write for them allow you to set new values, even on an individual basis.